# Convert any variable to string in C

Tags: c, string, stringify, stringification

Is is possible to convert any variable of any type to string?

I wrote the following

`#define TO_STRING(val) #val`

Is this a valid way of converting a variable into a string?

Comment: ok, I'm the one saying this so I will appear as the picky one: there are no strings in C.

Comment: @user2485710 That's a pretty weird statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code below will do your work. I uses the standard `sprintf` function, which prints data from any type to a string, instead to `stdout`. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INT_FORMAT "%d"
#define FLOAT_FORMAT "%f"
#define DOUBLE_FORMAT "%lf"
#define LL_FORMAT "%lld"
// ect ...

#define CONVERT_TO_STRING(FORMAT, VARIABLE, LOCATION) \
  do { \
    sprintf(LOCATION, FORMAT, VARIABLE); \
  } while(false)

int main() {
  char from_int[30];
  char from_float[30];
  char from_double[30];
  char from_ll[30];

  CONVERT_TO_STRING(INT_FORMAT, 34, from_int);
  CONVERT_TO_STRING(FLOAT_FORMAT, 34.234, from_float);
  CONVERT_TO_STRING(DOUBLE_FORMAT, 3.14159265, from_double);
  CONVERT_TO_STRING(LL_FORMAT, 9093042143018LL, from_ll);

  puts(from_int);
  puts(from_float);
  puts(from_double);
  puts(from_ll);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the reason of this while ??   do { \
    sprintf(LOCATION, FORMAT, VARIABLE); \
  } while(false)

Comment: @user2407394 just for safety :)

Comment: Recommend `%e` rather than `%f`.  Compare `printf("%e %f\n", 1.23e-8, 1.23e-8); printf("%e %f\n", 1.23e+50,  1.23e+50);` `1.230000e-08 0.000000`  `1.230000e+50 22999999999999994846185700645503654167417200000000.000000`

Comment: Can I print a variable's value without knowing its type? Like a general placeholder or a general way of printing anything out?

Answer (score 3):

You will get a string version of the variable's *name*, i.e. it will convert `a` to `"a"`. The `#`when used like this is called the [stringification operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification).

For example:

```
#define TO_STRING(val) #val

int main(void)
{
  const int a = 12;
  print("a is %s\n", TO_STRING(a));
  return 0;
}
```

This will print `a is a`.

What do you expect to happen?

You can't get the variable's *value*, of course, since that's not available when the pre-processor runs (which is at compile-time).

Answer (score 3):

try this will work with integers: edit the format string for other data types.

```
sprintf(str,"%d",value);
```